# Kali Linux in virtual hard drive .vmdk not working with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I was trying to install Kali Linux 2016.1 32bit on VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04.1 64bit system. Every time I tried to install it after selecting graphical install it ended with giving an error of `End Kernel Panel`. So I downloaded and installed VMware player and created a virtual machine and installed Kali Linux on it.
Then I created a VM on VirtualBox and used the virtual hard drive .vmdk of Kali Linux created by VMware player.
Now whenever I select the Kali Linux on gurb boot menu it gives me the same `End kernel Panic` error but works fine with VMware player.
So any solutions for that I can solve it and run Kali Linux on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after enabling virtualization from BIOS settings. Now it works.